# VBA string concatenation to build formula

Tags: vba, excel

Probably a very easy fix but struggling at the moment. I'm trying to put together a string that will then be used to fill a cell. It has reference to worksheet in another file and therefore uses single quotes.

I've tried building it out separately, and the string works when pushed to a MsgBox, however it doesn't work when trying to use as a formula:

```
ExtractPath = "'[GeneralExtract.xlsx]GeneralExtract'!$A$1:$B$6126"
StartCell.Formula = "=vlookup(R[0]C[1]," & ExtractPath & ", 2, FALSE)"
```

This gives a 1004 error. It's just the vlookup range that is causing me issue, the rest works as expected.

Comment: Drop the = from ExtractPath

Comment: Apologies I've included in the full formula in the variable and managed to confuse myself even further, let me edit and start again

Comment: You are mixing R1C1 and A1 reference styles.  Pick one and change the other to match.

Comment: ah! thank you. can you absolute a R1C1?

Comment: Yes you can, just remove the []

Comment: final question, the columns in the formula are defaulting to the same as the column of the value that is being looked up, can i somehow do C[-18] (From R to A)

Comment: `$A$1:$B$6126` in R1C1 is `R1C1:R6126C2`  Since it is absolute it is not relative to the cell in which the formula is placed.

Comment: understood. all working, thanks!